# Quota exceeded for quota group 'AnalyticsDefaultGroup' and limit 'USER-100s' of service 'analyticsreporting.googleapis.com'

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api, google-reporting-api

I'm having problems with the quota limit for the Analytics Reporting API v4.
I am receiving the following error:

> { "error": { "code": 429, "message": "Quota exceeded for quota group
>   'AnalyticsDefaultGroup' and limit 'USER-100s' of service
>   'analyticsreporting.googleapis.com' for consumer
>   'project_number:xxx'.", "errors": [ { "message": "Quota exceeded for
>   quota group 'AnalyticsDefaultGroup' and limit 'USER-100s' of service
>   'analyticsreporting.googleapis.com' for consumer
>   'project_number:xxx'.", "domain": "global", "reason":
>   "rateLimitExceeded" } ], "status": "RESOURCE_EXHAUSTED" } }

As you can see on the picture from my developer console, I already increased the requests from 100 to 1000 per 100s per user. This change doesn't seem to be working on my current user.

[image]

I did 100 requests in 100s which succeeded, but the 101 request failed, even though 1000 should be possible.

Also my daily limit is far from being exceeded.
[image]

Do I have to create a new service account to make that work? Do I have to wait for the next day for the limit to be active? Do I have to set a limit in Google Analytics itself?